# Installing extensions on Visual Studio 2017 mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to install Visual Studio Market Place extensions on Visual Studio for Mac but.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention on VS2017 for Mac

Comment: @UnholySheep in all honesty, the accepted answer on the MSDN Forum isn't entirely correct. VS2017 for Mac _does_ support Extensions, albeit not the ones from the conventional Visual Studio Marketplace.

Answer (score 46):

Visual Studio 2017 for Mac is actually a different beast from Visual Studio for Windows. As you may know, it is originally based on Xamarin Studio which on its turn is an extended form of MonoDevelop.

Simply put, the extensions you'll find in the [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) **are not compatible** with Visual Studio 2017 for Mac.

VS2017 for Mac does have its own marketplace, which is accessible from the Extension Manager. You can access it from inside the IDE through:
**Visual Studio menu > Extensions**

In the Extension Manager, you'll find a pretty small list of available extensions. But a neat trick is to look at the source of the repositories, which is simply the old MonoDevelop catalog http://addins.monodevelop.com/

[image: Extension Manager in Visual Studio 2017 for Mac]

Wrapping it up, you can add third party extension url's or install community packages through a file, but basically put there is not a lot more that you can get with the same experience and broad offering like the 'regular' Marketplace.

Comment: how to install Angular5TemplateCore2 in VS2017 MAC? I cant find any extension for it?

Comment: I found that you can install many templates from the command line on VS Mac. **`dotnet new angular -o Angular.NETCore`** will get you the Angular template. I then delete the **`ClientApp`** directory and recreate it with the global Angular installed on my computer. **`ng new ClientApp --style=scss --routing`**