# How do I adjust the column ruler in Visual Studio 2017 for Mac Community Edition?

Tags: ide, editor, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-mac

The column ruler defaults to the 80th character which is way too small. How do I adjust this? (I circled it in red below)

I tried looking for extensions, but according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44825432/8462094) I can't install things like Productivity Power Tools that give me the option to adjust this.

Is there a plist file somewhere that I can edit?

This issue is super frustrating to me, so any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: The column ruler circled in red]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can configure this in the preferences dialog. Select Source Code - Code Formatting. Then select the type of file you want to configure. Most code formatting styles inherit from **Text file** so you may just want to select that.

[image: Preferences dialog]

Then change the **Desired file width** setting. By default it is 80.

Comment: Wow, I was scouring the "Text Editor" section, and couldn't find it. I can't believe I glossed over the "Source Code" section. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have checked all settings in Visual Studio 2017 for Mac and I don't find any settings could change the column ruler's size. And I also searching in Visual Studio -> Extensions in Visual Studio for Mac, there also doesn't have such extension could adjust the column ruler.

So I submit this requirement to Visual Studio for Mac User Voice site. You could vote it and add comments from below link.

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/563332-visual-studio-for-mac/suggestions/31250842-column-ruler-size