# Web Essentials on Visual Studio MacOS

Tags: macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, web-essentials

I've installed **Visual Studio 2017 for MacOS** and i would like to know if its possible to install Web Essentials (and other similar extensions) on that VS version?

I tried to manually select the .vsix file from VS but nothing happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing extensions on Visual Studio 2017 mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825177/installing-extensions-on-visual-studio-2017-mac)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825177/installing-extensions-on-visual-studio-2017-mac) indicates that the standard Visual Studio extensions do not work on the Mac version because it is based on an entirely different product, Xamarin Studio. Microsoft bought Xamarin a while back, so it looks like they've just taken the Xamarin product, modified it a little, and rebranded it.

There is, however, a collection of extensions for Visual Studio for Mac, and you can take a look at the question I linked to to find instructions on how to install those. I have no idea is Visual Studio Essentials is available for the Mac version, since I'm currently unable to view that extension repository. I think that it is unlikely that you'll find a version for the Mac version of Visual Studio, but check it out and see if you can find the extension or something similar..