# How to install .NET Portability Analyzer on Visual Studio 2017 (Mac)

Tags: .net, macos, visual-studio

The .NET Portability Analyzer is a good tool and gives good insights when we are planning to migrate old applications.

I can't download the .vsix file and get Visual Studio to install it on Mac and I can't find a way to locate it via the extensions (adding repository).

I am happy to use the Console version of the app but would love to see that in action within the IDE.

**Note:** I did notice the question "[Installing extension on Visual Studio 2017 mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825177/installing-extensions-on-visual-studio-2017-mac) which is closed. The answer tells me why things are different in Visual Studio Mac but I don't see a way out to installing the Portability Analyzer.

Comment: As of today there is no plugin to VS on the Mac. You might be lucky with the CLI version.