# How to install extensions on Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 on Mac

Tags: javascript, c#

Could someone explain in detail how to install extensions on Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, because I'm having huge difficulties, I cannot create Projects like on Windows version "Modeling projects" (files with .csproj).

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44825432/6160965) on a similair question.