# .VSIX File Glitch on VS Mac?

Tags: visual-studio

I use Visual Studio 2021 for Mac, and whenever I try to install a .vsix file(cause all color themes use them for some reason) it doesn't install and instead does this. Any solutions? Thanks! [image]

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44825432/2137382) suggests that Visual Studio for Mac doesn't support extensions through the Visual Studio Marketplace. So, it's just opening the file as if it were a binary file. If I find something more current that states `.vsix` files aren't supported on a Mac, I'll submit it as an answer.

Comment: Oof, is there any way of getting the file to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a Mac, so this might be a partial answer.

It doesn't look like Visual Studio for Mac currently supports `.vsix` files, and thus doesn't support any extension shipped with that format. [According to a Visual Studio issue from 2017](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-install-extensions/67051?space=41&q=extensions), it instead supports `.mpack` files. The [instructions on developing extensions for Visual Studio (for Windows)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/starting-to-develop-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2019) has a note with a link labelled "[Extending Visual Studio for Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/extending-visual-studio-mac)" but it redirects to [a page detailing the more limited built-in ways for a user to customize their IDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/customizing-the-ide?view=vsmac-2019#workspace-layout).

That being said, I'm pretty sure Visual Studio for Mac is based on MonoDevelop, which has [add-ins](https://www.monodevelop.com/documentation/installing-add-ins/). Maybe Visual Studio for Mac does as well.