# MacOS Visual Studio 17.3 Library Manager

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I am trying to install [LibraryManager](https://github.com/mrward/LibraryManager), and the link suggests I should just be able to install it from the Gallery in the extensions manager. However on the Mac version of visual studio there is no option for this -

Am I Missing something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825177/installing-extensions-on-visual-studio-2017-mac

Comment: Is it possible to install the LibraryManager via a file then?

Comment: I have not got around to porting the Library Manager extension to Visual Studio for Mac 17.x